# What happens on pressing Ctrl-T in a terminal when a program is running?

Tags: terminal, process, osx, bsd

When I press <kbd>Ctrl+T</kbd> while some program is running in a terminal, I get some extra output, e.g.:

```
$ ping -q -c 100 google.com
PING google.com (172.217.16.46): 56 data bytes
load: 2.39  cmd: ping 5374 running 0.00u 0.00s
2/2 packets received (100.0%) 33.914 min / 34.169 avg / 34.423 max
...
```

Where does the output come from? Are there any other useful shortcuts that can be handled by a terminal?

Comment: I believe this is a BSD (only?) thing. `Ctrl+T` requests status info from the terminal driver.

Comment: Searching for *Ctrl-T* shows [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41529/what-is-linux-for-openvms-dcl-ctrl-t).

Comment: `Ctrl-T` goes back to at least TOPS-20 on the DESCSYSTEM-20.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On some Unix-style systems (BSDs and macOS), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> sends  `SIGINFO` to the running process. Some commands handle this directly; otherwise, it’s handled by the kernel, and that’s what produces the output you’re seeing.

[SIGINFO on GNU Linux (Arch Linux) missing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/179481/86440) has more on the topic.